# Should the access tokens expire?

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to set access tokens to never expire?  Or should we ask the user of the application to periodically re-enter their credentials?

Comment: That is all a matter of *opinion*.  The responsible thing would be to to never use `no_expiry` so that the user and your app have a little more protection against exploits.  The API takes care of reprompting the user as required.

Comment: also off-topic - this question isn't specific to SE